# has anyone successfully built qt 5.0.0 from source on windows 32-bit, on mysis, using mingw 4.72?

Tags: windows-7, mingw, qt5, 32-bit

I have been programming in c++ for sometime now, but mainly console programs. i have learnt several data structures, pointers and i'm sure i'm capable of developing some simple software. so i decided to download qt and start learning how to create UIs, but the problem is that i have mingw 4.72 and qt 5.0 complained that it only works with win32API version 3.13 while my mingw installation has 3.17. so i decided to build qt 5.0.0 from source using the mingw 4.72,, but i'm getting compiler errors such as this

```
c:/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.0/qtbase/qmake/library/qmakeevaluator.cpp: in
member function 'void QMakeEvaluator::loadDefaults()':
c:/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.0/qtbase/qmake/library/qmakeevaluator.cpp:968:43:  
error: cannot convert 'wchar_t*' to 'LPSTR {aka char*}' for argument '1' to 'BOOL 
GetComputerNameA(LPSTR, PDWORD)'
make.exe: *** [qmakeevaluator.o] Error 1 *** qtbase/configure exited with non-zero   
status..
```

so my question is this, has anybody successfully built a stable qt 5.0 for 32-bit windows 7, using mingw 4.72? i have all the prerequisites, perl, ruby and python....

Comment: Check it out: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTSDK-1166

Comment: thanks for the info, and have you built it successfully?

Comment: No, I'm sorry, I just searched Google for you. I hope it works, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

i decided to go with version 4.8.4, and the configuring has gone smoothly. yet to to type mingw-make since i have been told it takes a while to finish. there is a good guide here http://wiki.batcom-it.net/index.php?title=Building_Qt_on_Windows_%28MinGW%29. i hope it helps someone...